# Can't get the information from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and to learn it I'm trying to make a simple application without scaffolding.

I generated a controller Foos, a model Foo and created 4 foos in the database. Then I tried to get /Foos/ and got an error. So I wrote

```
def index
    @foos = Foo.all
end
```

in the controller and created a view.

The view looks like

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
    <div><% foo.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

The logs from console and from the server looks the same

```
Processing by FoosController#index as HTML
Foo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos"
```

But when I get Foos from the rails console it shows me foos and the view just creates 4 empty divs. Why? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @foos.each do |foo| %>
    <div><%= foo.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

You need equal sign for output to the view